# What will be output of the following prolog simple code and why?

Tags: prolog

```
eight(A,B):-
    eight(A,[],B).

eight([],X,X).
eight([A|B],C,X):-
    eight(B,[A|C],X).
```

Query

```
?- eight([a,b,c],X)
```

Answer (score 1):

The predicate `eight` that you wrote there reverses a list.  You could have found this out by just trying with different lists, and seeing the outcome.

### Down the rabbit hole

As I understand it, when you run `eight([a,b,c],X).` it finds the first/only predicate that matches `eight/2`, and unifies `[a,b,c]` with `A`, it keeps the variable `X` as a random variable, probably like `_G1234`.  Next it calls the body of the predicate as:

`eight([a,b,c], [], _G1234)`

This checks for predicates it can unify its arguments with.  Since it cannot unify the empty list with `[a,b,c]`, it finds your second `eight/3` predicate (`eight([A|B],C,X)`) and unifies `[A|B]` with `[a|[b,c]]`, `C` with `[]`, and passes the unknown variable along for the ride.  It then calls the body of the predicate with the newly unified variables as:

`eight([b,c], [a|[]], _G1234)`

This checks again for predicates it can unify its arguments with.  Again, the empty list cannot be unified with `[b,c]`, so it finds your second `eight/3` predicate again, and unifies `[A|B]` with `[b|[c]]`, `C` with `[a|[]]`, and passes that unknown variable along again.  So it calls the body of this predicate as:

`eight([c], [b|[a|[]]], _G1234)`

Once again, it checks for predicates it can unify its arguments.  And once again, the first predicate it can unify its arguments with is your second `eight/3` predicate.  So it unifies `[A|B]` with `[c|[]]`, `C` with `[b|[a|[]]]` and passes that unknown along again.  It calls the body now as:

`eight([], [c|[b|[a|[]]]], _G1234)`

Now when it checks for predicates it can unify with, it finds your first `eight/3` predicate.  It unifies the empty list with the empty list, `X` with `[c|[b|[a|[]]]]` and since there's only one `X`, as far as prolog is concerned, that is placed in both positions.  So it ends up unifiying `_G1234` with `X` which in this case is `[c|[b|[a|[]]]]`.  We end up with something that looks like this:

`eight([], [c|[b|[a|[]]]], [c|[b|[a|[]]]])`

For the sake of simplicity, I'm going to simplify those lists to:

`eight([], [c,b,a], [c,b,a])`

### Up predicate

This predicate has no body, so it is actually a fact.  When a fact is unified, a valid solution is considered to have been found.  So prolog starts backing up the chain until it reaches a decision point and displays a valid goal.  It goes to the previous predicate as `eight([c], [b,a], [c,b,a])`, then up again as `eight([b,c], [a], [c,b,a])`, and again as `eight([a,b,c], [], [c,b,a])`, and finally to where it started in the clause of your `eight/2` predicate as `eight([a,b,c], [c,b,a])`.  So it has successfully unified your original `X` as you posed the query.  And displays this to you as:

`X = [c, b, a].`

Being that you have no other decision points in your program, this is the only possible goal and control is returned to you for more queries.

In the future, if you want to know how a predicate works, turn on [tracing](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=trace/0), with swi-pl it's just the `trace\0` predicate in the repl.

Answer (score 0):

eight(A,B):-eight(A,[],B).

eight([],X,X).

eight([A|B],C,X) :- eight(B,[A|C],X).

Be careful with Prolog it can be very pedantic.

After getting your rules to run and running your query. I got

eight([a,b,c],x).
false.

Comment: You got that because `x` is not a variable in Prolog. It can be "pedantic," remember? :)